# Change style attribute when two variables have same value

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I have 10 Elements where 2 of them always have a other data-attribute name, like 2 Elements have `data-spot="lorem1"` and the other two `data-spot="lorem2"` etc.
The Elements should be shown when I am in a specific position on the website - I already have the Function to get my position and it can output the position as a string like `lorem1` `lorem2` ...

The class `elementspot` has the style attribute `opacity: 0;` now I want to change the opacity of the Elements which have the data-spot name exactly like the `loc` output.

I did something like:

```
function showElement(loc) {

    $(".elementspot").find("[data-spot='" + loc + "']")
}
```

But I don't really come further than that..

Comment: Keep going! You're on the right track (though you don't want to use `find` on the result of `$()` in this case because you're not looking *within* those, you want to long *among* them; you just want a single `$(".elementspot[data-spot='" + loc + "']")`. Now you just need to see how to set the `opacity`. You can do it directly via `css`, or (I would suggest) by adding a class that overrides the `opacity` from the `elementspot` class. If you read through [the jQuery documentation](api.jquery.com/), you shouldn't have much trouble.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the motivation :D What if I just give every Element Group a different classname and change the opacity when "loc" puts out the same name as the class ? is there already a post there I don't find any..

Comment: You already have the `data-` attribute, no need for another class. But you could do it that way as well.

Comment: Please update the question to show the (minimal) HTML of these elements.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".elementspot").find("[data-spot='" + loc + "']")` will try to find elements that have the relevant `data-spot` attribute **inside** elements with the `elementspot` class. From your description, though, the `elementspot` elements directly have the `data-spot` attribute. So to find elements that both have the class *and* have the `data-spot` attribute, use a compound selector:

```
$(".elementspot[data-spot='" + loc + "']")
```

or with a template literal, which makes it easier to avoid errors in the string:

```
$(`.elementspot[data-spot="${loc}"]`)
```

Then you need to do something to override the opacity on the elements. I'd use another class (perhaps `show`): `.addClass("show")`. (You might need to remove that class from other elements if `showElement` has been called before.)

So for instance:

```js
function showElement(loc) {
    // Remove class from other elements that may have it
    $(`.elementspot[data-spot]`).removeClass("show");
    // Add it to these ones
    $(`.elementspot[data-spot="${loc}"]`).addClass("show");
}
```

with CSS along these lines:

```css
.elementspot {
    opacity: 0;
}
.elementspot.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function showElement(loc) {
    // Remove class from other elements that may have it
    $(`.elementspot[data-spot]`).removeClass("show");
    // Add it to these ones
    $(`.elementspot[data-spot="${loc}"]`).addClass("show");
}

$("input[data-loc]").on("click",  ({currentTarget}) => {
    const loc = currentTarget.getAttribute("data-loc");
    showElement(loc);
});
```

```css
.elementspot {
    opacity: 0;
}
.elementspot.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementspot" data-spot="lorem1">data-spot=lorem1 (first)</div>
<div class="elementspot" data-spot="lorem1">data-spot=lorem1 (second)</div>
<div class="elementspot" data-spot="lorem2">data-spot=lorem2 (first)</div>
<div class="elementspot" data-spot="lorem2">data-spot=lorem2 (second)</div>
<div class="elementspot" data-spot="lorem3">data-spot=lorem3 (first)</div>
<div class="elementspot" data-spot="lorem3">data-spot=lorem3 (second)</div>

<input type="button" value="Show lorem1" data-loc="lorem1">
<input type="button" value="Show lorem2" data-loc="lorem2">
<input type="button" value="Show lorem3" data-loc="lorem3">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```